# Outputing deeply nested JSON to HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, nested, output

So I can access the data I need by going to `console.log(data.response[0].entities.urls);`but how do I output the second array of entities into a HTML format. Is there a way of breaking up the JSON data using a for loop or something?

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$.getJSON('http://www.jamesam.ac/dev202/sdillon3/', function (data) {

    var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';

    $.each(data.response, function (key, val) {

            output += '<li>';
            output += '<img src="' + val.user.profile_image_url + '" alt="' + val.text + '" />';
            output += '<h3>' + val.user.name + '</h3>';
            output += '<h4><i>' + val.user.screen_name + '</i></h4>';
            output += '<p>' + val.text + '</p>';
            output += '</li>';

    }); // go through each post 
    output += '</ul>';


    $('#feed').html(output);

    console.log(data)
    //console.log(data.response[0].entities.urls);//

});
```

});

Comment: post json to solve this issue

Comment: how do you want the values to be displayed

Comment: see an example of `url` http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/F5PEx/3/

Comment: Not sure if I'm being clear enough, but I'm having trouble outputting the JSON data in console.log(data.response[0].entities.urls); because it's so deeply nested. How do I output it like I have the other values?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Just needed to write a good old for loop.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$.getJSON('http://www.jamesam.ac/dev202/sdillon3/', function (data) {

    var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';

    $.each(data.response, function (key, val) {

            output += '<li>';
            output += '<img src="' + val.user.profile_image_url + '" alt="' + val.text + '" />';
            output += '<h3>' + val.user.name + '</h3>';
            output += '<h4><i>' + val.user.screen_name + '</i></h4>';
            output += '<p>' + val.text + '</p>';

            for(var i = 0; i < val.entities.urls.length; i++)
            {
                output+= '<a href="' + val.entities.urls[i].url +'" </a>';
            }
            output += '</li>';

    }); // go through each post 
    output += '</ul>';

    $('#feed').html(output);

});
```

});